# how to interpolate data in csv file with rolling/moving average? (Python)

Tags: python, csv, time-series, interpolation, moving-average

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
2000-10-01,0.2214
2000-10-02,0.18304
2000-10-03,0.20181
2000-10-04,0.19469
2000-10-05,
2000-10-06,
2000-10-07,0.11495
2000-10-08,0.23528
2000-10-09,0.16796
```

but on some days the values are missing, sometimes just one day, sometimes some weeks without any values. is there a possibility to interpolate or fill the gaps with an rolling or moving average with maybe 15 days before and after the missing date? 
 my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
ts=pd.read_csv('sum.csv', parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])
ts_inter=ts.fillna(pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(ts,7))
ts_inter.to_csv('moving_average_ET.csv')
```

The problem is, that there is no gap filled in the output file. It's the same like the original data.

Comment: fill NA values in dataframe: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna  read dataframe from csv file: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html#pandas.io.parsers.read_csv

Comment: I'd recommend installing [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org).  Many kinds of interpolation and imputation are possible.

Comment: yes I do use pandas. And i know that there is a function "rolling_mean" and that i can fill the NA. But I don't know how to combine it :/

Comment: So why not to look for examples of rolling_mean uses? Really these sort of questions are like: hey dudes, why would not you solve my problem as I do not want to dig into it... You do not even write about data in any structure loaded into memory (neither you write about updating data directly in a file), you just assume that somebody will write all the code for you. Great idea...

Comment: If your question is about filling in the gaps, maybe your example data should contain one of those gaps. And an expected output as well.

Comment: in this case it should  fill the gap for the 5th with the mean of 2nd - 4th October and 6th - 8th, that mean the result should be 0.18595. For the 6th october the 7 day moving average should just move and be calculated from 3rd - 9th Oct (0.18294).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you're looking for something like

```
df.fillna(pd.rolling_mean(df, 7, min_periods=1).shift(-3))
```

Example:

```
>>> df
                  1
0                  
2000-10-01  0.22140
2000-10-02  0.18304
2000-10-03  0.20181
2000-10-04  0.19469
2000-10-05      NaN
2000-10-06      NaN
2000-10-07  0.11495
2000-10-08  0.23528
2000-10-09  0.16796

[9 rows x 1 columns]
>>> df = df.fillna(pd.rolling_mean(df, 7, min_periods=1).shift(-3))
>>> df
                   1
0                   
2000-10-01  0.221400
2000-10-02  0.183040
2000-10-03  0.201810
2000-10-04  0.194690
2000-10-05  0.185954
2000-10-06  0.182938
2000-10-07  0.114950
2000-10-08  0.235280
2000-10-09  0.167960

[9 rows x 1 columns]
```

which seems to match the numbers you described in your comment.  I think what's happening with your code is that your `rolling_mean` isn't producing any non-NaN values because it never thinks it has enough data to make an estimate.

Comment: could you explain why did you use `shift(-3)` here? I searched about `shift` and it is used in `timeseries`. However, i still did not fully understand why `shift` was used here. Thanks!

Comment: @i.n.n.m - Here the old `pd.rolling_mean()` is used, where a `rolling().mean()` is the new format.  The `shift(-3)` is moving it from a right windowed problem to a centered window.  This could also be accomplished by usining `df.rolling(window=7,min_periods=1,center=True).mean()`